# PHP prepared statments with select query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, prepared-statement, sqlsrv

I just started learning PHP today and am trying to write a few queries using prepared statements. so far I have this:

```
$query = "select * from users where 1 = ?";
$result = sqlsrv_query($connection,$query,array(1));
if($result === false){
echo "error";
}

while($row =  sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
print_r($row);
}
```

It produces the desired result (simply printing everything returned).
I am struggling on making it a prepared query, to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @Akintunde OP is using [tag:sql-server], not [tag:mysql].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

This already is a prepared query, where the third argument of `sqlsrv_query` is the array of variables you want to bind.